# jQuery selection from multiple variables which might be null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a jQuery selection from multiple variables.

Each variable can be:

- referencing a DOM element, OR
- be null
- (bonus) be undefined.
- (bonus) be a jQuery selection itself, to be merged into the target selection.

The final selection should:

- Contain only DOM elements. No null or undefined entries, no nested arrays/selections.
- Contain each element only once.

The code should be simple and short, without too much if/else.

### What I tried so far

The first thing I tried was `jQuery([a, b, c])`. Problem here is that null and undefined are not discarded, and selections inserted as nested selections instead of being merged.

I could filter the array before sending it to jQuery, but this would make things more verbose.

A solution that seems to work is `jQuery(a).add(b).add(c)`. Perhaps this is the best it can be, but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering seems the only option for me

Here is the simplest solution I could come with.

```
jQuery([a,b,c].filter(v => v));
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for something even shorter. But I am accepting this, perhaps it is really the best solution available.